# How can stdout be captured or suppressed for Go(lang) testing?

Tags: go

How can stdout be captured or suppressed for Go testing?

I am trying to teach myself go(lang) testing.  In the code below, myshow.LoadPath prints lots of information to stdout (which is a normal side effect).     It does however make for very noisy output when I run "go test"    Is there a way to suppress or capture stdout?

For comparison, I'm thinking about something like this from the python world. http://pytest.org/latest/capture.html#captures

```
package slideshow_test

import (
    "os"
    "testing"

    "github.com/golliher/go-hpf/slideshow"
)

func setupTest() {
    myshow := slideshow.Slideshow{Name: "This is my show"}
    myshow.LoadPath("..")

}

func TestStub(t *testing.T) {
    if true == false {
        t.Fail()
    }
}

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    setupTest()
    os.Exit(m.Run())

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`os.Stdout` which is used by the `fmt.Printf` and others is just a variable. So you can overwrite it at any time and restore it back when necessary. https://golang.org/pkg/os/#pkg-variables

Comment: Thank you.  This is helpful.  I was hoping there might be a feature of the testing package that would capture stdout (ala pytest).  It seems like a common thing to need.   If that's not possible, yours looks like it will let me move forward and I'll accept this as an answer.

Comment: To be honest, I do not know about any. But you can consider to [test examples](https://blog.golang.org/examples). However, I assume that it is what you exactly want to do.

Comment: if just want to discard it use this: `os.Stdout,_ = os.Open(os.DevNull)`

Comment: `log.SetOutput(ioutil.Discard)` as suggested on https://golangcode.com/disable-log-output-during-tests/

Answer (score 10):

The output can be [*suppressed*](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21461#issuecomment-348374826)
by running the tests with `go test .`:

> `$ go help test`
>
> Go test runs in two different modes: local
>   directory mode when invoked with no package arguments (for example,
>   'go test'), and package list mode when invoked with package arguments
>   (for example 'go test math', 'go test ./...', and even 'go test .').
>
> In local directory mode, go test compiles and tests the package
>   sources found in the current directory and then runs the resulting
>   test binary. In this mode, caching (discussed below) is disabled.
>   After the package test finishes, go test prints a summary line showing
>   the test status ('ok' or 'FAIL'), package name, and elapsed time.
>
> In package list mode, go test compiles and tests each of the packages
>   listed on the command line. If a package test passes, go test prints
>   only the final 'ok' summary line. If a package test fails, go test
>   prints the full test output. If invoked with the -bench or -v flag, go
>   test prints the full output even for passing package tests, in order
>   to display the requested benchmark results or verbose logging.

Answer (score 10):

To suppress the output during the test I use the following code. I fixes output as well as logging. After test is done it resets the output streams.

```
func TestStartStowWrongCommand(t *testing.T) {
 defer quiet()()   
 ...                      
}

func quiet() func() {
 null, _ := os.Open(os.DevNull)
 sout := os.Stdout
 serr := os.Stderr
 os.Stdout = null
 os.Stderr = null
 log.SetOutput(null)
 return func() {
  defer null.Close()
  os.Stdout = sout
  os.Stderr = serr
  log.SetOutput(os.Stderr)
 }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work properly because evaluation of `quiet()()` seems to be deferred at runtime as a whole. It works using `q := quiet(); defer q()`.

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly what you are asking for but still might be helpful.

You can use `t.Log` (http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#T.Log) and `t.Logf` (http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#T.Logf) methods in the test method. The output will be printed only if the test fails or the `-test.v` flag is set.

I also would suggest to use `log` package to print to the console in `myshow.LoadPath`. Then you can disable (or capture) the output in the test by setting custom writer using `log.SetOutput`

Comment: While you're right it wasn't what I was asking for, it is generally useful and I wasn't aware of those functions.    So.. Thank you!

Comment: Also, your advice on converting to using log for myshow.LoadPath is well taken.   I'm getting that recommendation from others too so I'm going to look into doing as you suggest.

Comment: Is there any way to read from the error log within a test, so as to make assertions about it?

Answer (score 2):

You can silence the os.Stdout like [grzegorz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/450989/grzegorz-%c5%bbur) suggested.

The only thing I want to add is keep in mind that some programs checks the err that returns from fmt.Print, so you need to assign to os.Stdout a writable null device like so:

```
os.Stdout, _ = os.OpenFile(os.DevNull, os.O_WRONLY, 0)
```