# How to stop fmt.print() from printing to the output?

Tags: go

I'm using a package which has some `fmt.print()`s in the code, and I want to stop them from printing to the output. I want to suppress them without changing the code inside the package and only by adding some lines to my `main.go`.

Is it possible to force `fmt` not to log prints to the output?

Comment: Use a logger instead of fmt.Print(), so you can configure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, just divert `os.Stdout` and/or `os.Stderr` e.g.:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    temp := os.Stdout
    os.Stdout = nil    // turn it off
    packageFunctions() // call your package functions here
    os.Stdout = temp   // restore it
    fmt.Println("Bye")
}
func packageFunctions() {
    fmt.Println("Hi")
}
```

Output:

```
Bye
```

---

You may divert it to a temp file:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    tmpfile, err := ioutil.TempFile("", "example")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(tmpfile.Name())
    // defer os.Remove(tmpfile.Name()) // clean up

    temp := os.Stdout
    os.Stdout = tmpfile
    packageFunctions() // call you package functions here

    if err := tmpfile.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    os.Stdout = temp // restore it
    fmt.Println("Bye")
}
func packageFunctions() {
    fmt.Println("Hi")
}
```

---

And see:

[How to copy os.Stdout output to string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51183462/how-to-copy-os-stdout-output-to-string-variable)

[How can stdout be captured or suppressed for Go(lang) testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31663229/how-can-stdout-be-captured-or-suppressed-for-golang-testing)